# Express.js Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I have been receiving this error a lot lately and although I have been investigating as to why I might be receiving it I am completely stumped. I know from previous research that this error is usually associated with subsequent res.send() calls where the second one tries to set headers after a res.end() has been executed.

The process is a series of promises that basically starts with getting an object from the database, processing it where each promise uses the result of the previous one to fetch something else from the database and process it until we finally build an object and send it back to the user.

Another thing is that we get hammered with over 2000 requests per second, and after a while I start seeing errors in the logs. The full error message is this, which is then followed by a bunch of Express Timeout errors:

```
Can't set headers after they are sent.
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
   at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)
   at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:59:22)
   at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:522:10)
   at ServerResponse.res.jsonp (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:236:8)
   at validator.validate.then.then.then.then.then.then.then.then.then.fail.res.send.code (<path-to-module>/module.js:131:29)
   at _fulfilled (/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
   at self.promiseDispatch.done (/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
   at /node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
   at flush (/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
```

And here is the code:

```
           app.get('/endpoint', function (req, res) {

            validator.validate(req.query, {
                // check query to see if valid

            }).then(function (valResult) {
               // if result passes validation get application id from database

            }).then(function (app) {
            // do a bunch of IO operations to build resulting object
            }).then
            }).then
            }).then
            }).then(function (result) {

                // This is where I am getting the error

                if (result.platform === 'mobile') {
                    res.jsonp({code: 100, message: 'SUCCESS', data: result});
                }
                else {
                    res.send({code: 100, message: 'SUCCESS', data: result});
                }

            }).fail(function (error) {

                if (error.stack) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                    console.log(error.stack);
                    res.send({code: 500, message: 'FAIL_SYSTEM', data: error.message});
                } else {
                    res.send(error);
                }

            });

        }
```

Any ideas on what might be happening? Is it possible that, due to the amount of requests, certain promises are executing later and trying to send after the response has already been sent?

Answer (score 0):

promises will work like this 
he i am will explain on small example using Q npm lib in nodejs 
validate.js

```
var q = require('q');
function validate (query)
{
var deferred = q.difere();
------validation logic -----
if (validation success)
{
deferred.resolve(validationResult);
}
else
{
deferred.reject(validationResult);
}
return deferred;
}
```

in controller you can write promises

```
  var validator = require('./validator.js');
     app.get('/endpoint', function (req, res) {

                validator.validate(req.query)
                .then(function (valResult) {

                    //same db query 

                     Model.find({},function(error, result){

                     if(!error)
                      {
                      return result ;
                      }
                      });

                     }

                    ).then(function (result) {

                    // This is where I am getting the error

                    if (result.platform === 'mobile') {
                        res.jsonp({code: 100, message: 'SUCCESS', data: result});
                    }
                    else {
                        res.send({code: 100, message: 'SUCCESS', data: result});
                    }

                }).fail(function (error) {

                    if (error.stack) {
                        console.log(error.message);
                        console.log(error.stack);
                        res.send({code: 500, message: 'FAIL_SYSTEM', data: error.message});
                    } else {
                        res.send(error);
                    }



                });

            }).
```